# Add apply button to laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on job engine project at the moment of this project I need to add button to ads for apply the vacancy by users and I need to this apply button send user data to the publisher company. for more understanding i give an example:

1. company will publish ads
2. user click on apply button in that ad
3. the button will get info from user profile and send it to company dashboard includes `name,email,about, etc. but the most important is to send user CV's link to download` by the company.

my question is: who can I approach that idea? currently I'm out of idea how to do that, i need to know what functions I have to use to make this happen?

thanks.

Comment: There is too little information in your post to allow people to effectively help you mate. You need to at least provide your models structure and database schema as the bare minimum. If that's too much for you at this point, I suggest subscribing to something like laracasts.com and taking the beginners lessons on building apps in Laravel, it will help you immensely.

Comment: @YasenSlavov I'm not working on any code in this case at the moment so i don't have any code to share, i just need consultation in this step which Exprator did in comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i will give you the steps hoping that all the data of a student is saved in the database

1. the user should be logged in
2. get the id of the logged in user on click on apply button, like a form where it will call a controller function where you will retrieve the id of the authenticated user.
3. in that function query the database table of user and select all information
4. wrap them and send an email or a message to the particular company.

hope it helps

Comment: thanks @exprator it light me up really but in no.4 i'm still confuse how to that? and for no.2 should i use specific js library such as(reactjs, angular etc.)  or just native Jquery would be enough?

Comment: email is available in laravel only, you can check laravel documentation to send email with data

Comment: how about no.2 ?

Comment: Check for getting id of logged in user in laravel, and check a select statement where id= logged in user id, and then you will get all the details

Comment: thanks man. appreciate that.