# send user data to another user in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I try to send user data stored in database to another users after first user click on button.

I asked [Add apply button to laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44082377/add-apply-button-to-laravel-5-4) this question before, and I'm trying to do what was suggested to me, currently i have this code:

```
@if (Auth::guest())

@else
    <div class="text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-info btn-round" href="#" id="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
            <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_send"></i> APPLY NOW
        </a>
    </div>
@endif
```

first of all I know my code is not complete and I don't know how to finish it!
Second I have no idea how to pass data to second user.

PS: I need code not just suggestions I already got suggestions and I'm stuck in that.

Thanks.

Comment: You need code? Before that can you post what have you tried so far.

Comment: @BikashPaul that's all i have in above, I'm totally stuck. that's my blade code and i have no code in any controller etc. to make this happen.

Comment: @Chay22 already i no have problem with getting users info my problem is to send it to second user.

Comment: What kind of "send" you're referring to? Email? create a route, form and a controller to handle that logic. Kinda private message? A table is good, another form and controller will also needed. This is unclear.

Comment: @Chay22 I want to send user1 data includes their(email,full name,and link of their cv) to user2 after user 1 click on send button. my sending way is by email also i want show notification to user 2 panels that they have new applies from user1 nameX.

Comment: @robertnicjoo Here is what you could do. On click apply put the value you want to send in some database table. the table might have following columns (receiver_id, email, cv_link, full_name, is_read) once the sender click apply now store the data in database. When the receiver logs in check if there is any data where receiver_id is equal to Auth::user()->id

Comment: @AatishSai do i have to make new controller/etc.? and how i get receiver_id as company_id then also i think i have to get ad_id as well cause 1 company could have many ads and they must know user applied to which ad right? could you give sample code or reference url of similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. create function on your controller to receive user id and get all user information

> ```
>    public function apply($id){
>           $data["users"] = User::where('id', $id)->get()->first();
>           return view("dashboard", $data)
>     }
> ```

2. create route with post or get method, in this section i use get method,

> `Route::get('/apply/{id}', 'YourController@apply');`

Your a href should like this

> ```
>   <a class="btn btn-info btn-round" href="apply/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
>      <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_send"></i> APPLY NOW
>   </a>
> ```

3. on your dashboard, declare user information using this script

> $user->name
>   $user->email`

etc,

Hope this can help your problem, any question please comment

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't work. and also i think we need save data as well so every time user who applied and company who got the request can see the history and info of ad was applied to.